# Python `template` equivalent

Tags: c++, python-3.x, oop, templates

What's the most effective equivalent to C++ templates in Python? e.g. how would I implement the following:

```
template<unsigned X, unsigned Y>
class SomeType {
...
}
```

My present thought is to use something like:

```
def FooFactory(*params):
  class FooCreated:
    # do stuff with params
    ...
  return FooCreated
```

But this feels incredibly hacky. What's the best way to created this behavior?

In my example, I also need FooCreated to be able to be subclassed.

Comment: How are these 2 code snippets related? What does the C++ code do with `X` and `Y` and how is there any relation to subclassing?

Comment: Take C++ and imagine that EVERY function and EVERY class was a template.  That's Python, out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: It's meaningless, you don't need an equivalent.**

Templates are a C++ mechanism allowing compile-time polymorphism: When instantiated with different types, different code is generated - which may act differently. It could be a templated function, or a templated class like in your example. This is significant because, in general, C++ is a statically-typed language. Thus, if you had:

```
template<unsigned X>
class SomeType {
   std::array<int, X> a;
}
```

then `SomeType<3>` and `SomeType<4>` are completely distinct types. You can't assign an instance of one into an instance of the other, you can't pass one to a function taking the other etc. Actually, they would be completely distinct even if the `a` member did not practically depend on `X` at all.

Python is a dynamically-typed language. So, you could define some variable, initializing it with a value of one type, and then replace that value with a value of another type altogether. In C++ terms, it's as though you had an `int x = 123;`, and you assigned it `std::string("hello")` - and it became an `std::string x` with value `"hello"s`. When your language has that, you don't need to bother with instantiating templates of types with different members etc - you just put whatever-type values you like in a variable, or an element of a list, or what-not.

See also:

- [An illustration of Python's dynamically-typed nature](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/is-python-dynamically-typed-language) (tutorialspoint.com)
- A [post](https://www.sitepoint.com/typing-versus-dynamic-typing/) (sitepoint.com) regarding static vs dynamic languages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would phrase template-kindof of things in Python:

```py
def funcGen(X, Y):
   def func(*args, **kwargs):
      //work  with X and Y class
```

Then wherever you want to *specialize the template*:

```py
myfunc = funcGen(myXClass, myYClass)
```